# jQuery: Delay a variables play() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I'm quite new to using jQuery and I'm using the following code to insert fade the `div` into the page.

`$("#DivIdGoesHere").delay(time).fadeIn(time);`

And i am using the following code to play the sound file.

```
var shrill_strings = new Audio('audio/shrill_strings.ogg');
shrill_strings.play();
```

I was just wondering if there is a way to do like :

`$shrill_stings.delay(time).play(time);`

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: As per my understanding `delay()` will not work here try `setTimeout` instead

Comment: How would I use that in this example? Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function () {
  new Audio('audio/shrill_strings.ogg').play();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `setTimeout()` js method here.

so instead of this:

```
$("#DivIdGoesHere").delay(time).fadeIn(time);
```

you can tryout with this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#DivIdGoesHere").fadeIn(time);
}, time);
```

---

So finally you can tryout the code like below:

```
var shrill_strings = new Audio('audio/shrill_strings.ogg');

setTimeout(function(){
    shrill_strings.play(time);
}, time);
```

where `var time` is the time in miliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

`delay(time)` works because all jQuery animations are added to a queue and they are extracted asynchronously from that queue to be executed. The `delay()` call basically adds another animation to the queue that doesn't change any property and forces subsequent animations in the queue to start later.

Since the `play()` method doesn't use jQuery's effects queue, delay has no effect on it.

As the other answers, mentioned, you need to use `setTimeout` directly to delay starting the sound:

```
var shrill_strings = new Audio('audio/shrill_strings.ogg');
setTimeout(shrill_strings.play.bind(shrill_strings), time);
```