# jQuery not working with video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadeout

I am trying to get a video to fade out using jQuery

On my html I have this video:

html

```
  <video playsinline autoplay loop id="video">
      <source src="myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

Then on my js file:

```
var $vid = $('#video');

$vid.delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
```

Instead of a fade out I get the video to just disappear. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: @nixkuroi your provided link is not kind of duplicate of this question. It's about delaying audio playing, while this is to fading out the video ***rendering*** - which may be the issue javascript cannot deal with easily.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: Delay a variables play() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850830/jquery-delay-a-variables-play-function)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some inconsistency between browsers for the handling of opacity applied to a video tag. Although the reason for the inconsistency is not clear for me, I were able to reproduce it and also to solve it by adding a parent div and fading the div.

So, html would be:

```
<div>
    <video playsinline autoplay loop id="video">
        <source src="myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Then, the JS would be:

```
var $vid = $('#video');
$vid.delay(2000).parent().fadeOut(500);
```